# Редакторы текста для больших файлов

Tags: javafx, textarea

Пытаясь загрузить в TextArea (JavaFX) файл размером 20MB и наблюдая, как приложение полностью повисло, я задумался, а как с этим справляются приложения типа NotePad++, UltraEdit, EmEditor и т.д. В них можно вертеть скролбар:) так как же это реализовано? Хотя бы в виде концепции, ну и если подскажете, как сделать подобное в javafx) Спасибо!

Comment: первое что приходит на ум бьём фаил на чанки и загружаем отдельными кусками, с размером в 1.5 экрана по мере прокрутки подгружать чанк с низу и удалять с верху, либо наоборот.

Comment: Но тогда такой вопрос: загружаем в NotePad++ файл 4GB и перетаскиваем скролл (не колесом, а ухватив указателем) сверху вниз. В результате этого на экране что-то появляется (прокручивается), что-то, похожее на реальный текст. Это несколько миллионов раз загружаются 1.5 экрана?)

Comment: Двойная буферизация и видно не будет что там где подгружаеться ну возьмите  3-4 экрана, суть в том что 4gb в оперативную память на 2gb вы никак не засуните.

Comment: То есть на Java ничего уже реализованного нет?

Comment: Приложение зависло в тот момент, когда вы начинаете скроллбар вертеть или же в тот момент, когда файл загружается?

Comment: 1. В момент загрузки. 2. Как любезно заметил @Naumov, файлы размером в 100GB не загрузится, при этом перечисленные редакторы справляются с такими файлами и скроллбар там работает.

Comment: Гуглите memory-mapped files.